# what is the sum of series using Dirichlet kernel?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I tried calculating the sum of this series using Dirichlet kernel but I have hit a dead end:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\sin(\theta n)}{2^n}$$

Any insight will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:**
Your sum is the imaginary part of $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\mathrm e^{i n \theta}}{2^n} $$
which is a geometric series.

Comment: thank you! 
i already wrote it as a sum of two geometric series but i got stuck with the algebra maybe I'm not doing something right

Comment: Do we agree that the sum of this geometric series is $S=1/(1-\tfrac{1}{2}e^{i\theta})$. Then, it suffices to compute $\tfrac{1}{2i}(S-\overline{S}).$

Comment: thank you!
yes this is what i did:)

but why can we asume that e^iθ/2  < 1

Comment: yes yes ofcoursss im so stupidddd